# How do I make the first page double sided in a single sided LaTeX document?

Tags: double-sided

How do I make the first page double sided in a single sided LaTeX document?

Is there a way that I can tell LaTeX that I want something on both sides of the first page, but everything after it to be single sided only, without making the whole document double sided and inserting a blank page after every page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997141/how-do-i-make-the-first-page-double-sided-in-a-single-sided-latex-document?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) allows one to switch your layout mid-document. So, you could set it as `twoside` for the first two pages, and then switch to the default ("oneside").

Here is a minimal document producing four pages, the first two are `twoside`, while the last two are *not* set in `twoside` mode, as shown by the `showframe` option to `geometry`.

[image: twoside switch to oneside]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{twoside}% Switch to twoside
\lipsum[1-10]
\restoregeometry% Restore to oneside
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was merely used to produce dummy text, *Lorem ipsum* style.