# no page break between shorthands and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, shorthands

I am using the following commands for my bibliography:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,firstinits=true,sorting=nty,sortcites=true,
      useprefix=false,isbn=false,maxnames=99,citetracker=true,
      backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Followed by the two commands at the end of the file

```
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[check=noshorthand]
```

With these settings, the shorthands are in one page, then a blank page follows, and then the bibliography is given. 
I would like the shorthands to immediately precede the bibliography, with maybe some lines of spacing, but no new page and blank page as well.

How can this be achieved. For your information, I am using MacTeX and TeXLive2014, so with the system frozen with such version.

Comment: This depends on the document class you use. Please add an MWE where we can see the class, so we can test our solutions.

Comment: Please do not change the question after you have received an answer. If you have an additional question or came across something else, please ask a follow-up question. Please make sure that you MWE can be compiled, as it stands now it does not produce a document with functioning `biblatex` citations.

Comment: You may also be able to fix this by temporarily setting the document to single-sided using [`geometry`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42253/28808).  I used a different approach as my thesis template conflicted with geometry, but I can't find an easy link.  You'd get a page break but no blank page (which are you trying to avoid?) This does of course assume you're double-sided to start with, but that seems quite likely (and also explains why a full MWE is a good idea)

Answer (score 4):

The headings for `\printbibliography` and `\printshorthands` are defined via `\section*` (for `article`-like classes) or  `\chapter*` (for `report` and `book`-like classes).

Whether or not a page break is inserted before a `\chapter*` or `\section*` is up to your document class.

We can stop LaTeX from breaking a page though, by temporarily disabling the commands that would do that. (See [@egreg's answer to Remove pagebreak after a chapter (Only for one chapter!)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131460/35864))

In your case that would probably be

```
\printshorthands
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

Now the page break before the normal bibliography is suppressed.

In a full MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{worman,geer,kant:kpv,brandt,cicero,baez/article}

\printshorthands
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\printbibliography
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

One could of course, alternatively fake the entire `\section*` or `\chpater*` command save for the page break and use that to define a new bibliography heading that we use for `\printbibliography`.

The command `\npbchapter` is `\chapter` with the page break surgically removed, we also define a new `bibheading` for `biblatex`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\npbchapter{\global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
\defbibheading{npbbib}[\bibname]{%
    \npbchapter*{#1}%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

use this as in

```
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib]
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\npbchapter{\global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
\defbibheading{npbbib}[\bibname]{%
    \npbchapter*{#1}%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{worman,geer,kant:kpv,brandt,cicero,baez/article}

\printshorthands
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib]
\end{document}
```